# Mapping db varchar to domain object bool

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I handle the mapping of strings in the database to bools in the domain model. Consider an example, storing coin flips in a database. For cases where there are usually only two values, like *heads* or *tails*.

<sup>*(**NOTE:** I realize it's better in most cases to also store bools in the database, but consider this an academic exercise)*</sup>

I want *True* in the model to end up *"heads"* in the database, and *"tails"* in the database to end up as *False* in the model.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from unittest import TestCase

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, id, is_heads):
        self.id = id
        self.is_heads = is_heads

metadata = MetaData()
db_foo = Table(
    'foo', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('side', String(5), nullable=False)) # heads or tails

def data_map():
    # what do I need to do here?
    mapper(Foo, db_foo)

class TestMaps(TestCase):
    def test_map(self):
        # Setup
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
        metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[db_foo])
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        data_map()
        expected = Foo(1, False)    
        # Exercise
        session.add(expected)
        session.flush()
        actual = session.query(Foo).first()    
        # Verify
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Augmenting Existing Types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types) section of documentation. The following should do the trick:

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types


class CoinFlipDataType(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        assert value in (True, False)
        return 'heads' if value else 'tails'

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        assert value in ('heads', 'tails'), value
        return value == 'heads'

    def copy(self):
        return CoinFlipDataType(self.impl.length)

def data_map():
    mapper(Foo, db_foo, properties={'is_heads': db_foo.c.side})

db_foo = Table(
    'foo', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('side', CoinFlipDataType(5), nullable=False))
```