# Can SqlAlchemey's TypeDecorator access multiple columns for handling special cases?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Building off my last [SqlAlchemy question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28467342/452274), yet again, I have another: How do I use a TypeDecorator to reference other columns in the same table? I'm not sure this is even possible from reading the documentation. The example isn't the best, but consider the use case where the mapping happens in converting a bool to a string value (is_heads -> 'heads' or 'tails'). What if sometimes I want to override this behavior, say if id = 1234 and just map the value 'edge' instead?

If this isn't possible with TypeDecorators, is there another a database-agnostic way to achieve the desired result?

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types    

class CoinFlipDataType(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        assert value in (True, False)

        # How to reference another column in the same table here?
        if id_column_value = special_case:
            return 'edge'

        return 'heads' if value else 'tails'

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        assert value in ('heads', 'tails', 'edge'), value

        # I don't care about that other column in this case

        return value == 'heads'

    def copy(self):
        return CoinFlipDataType(self.impl.length)

def data_map():
    mapper(Foo, db_foo, properties={'is_heads': db_foo.c.side})

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, id, is_heads):
        self.id = id
        self.is_heads = is_heads

db_foo = Table(
    'foo', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('side', CoinFlipDataType(5), nullable=False))
```

Comment: If you ever managed to solve this one, I'd be very keen to know how!!